# Rails and Activerecord, better way to uniform several objects to draw a comparison table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to draw a comparison table between some records in my table.

These are my classes.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :product_features
  has_many :features, through: :product_features
  has_many :product_features_groups
  has_many :feature_groups

end
```

This is my product class, where I store the products.
For the example my product is a smartphone.

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, through: :product_features
  has_many :product_features
end
```

This is my feature class, where I add the feature name, for example "resolution"

```
class ProductFeature < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_features_group
  has_one :feature_group, through: product_features_group

  default_scope { order(order: :desc) }
end
```

This is my join table between product and feature, where I store the value of the resolution for every product.

Then I have two other models to define the features group, so for example "Display".

```
class ProductFeaturesGroup < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :feature_group
  has_many :product_features

  default_scope { order(order: :desc) }

end

class FeatureGroup < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Basically my smartphone has some features group (display, connectivity, design) and for every feature group I have several features.

I have two ore more products to compare, and I have to draw a table. This will be very easy if every product has the same groups of features and the same features, but this is not my case.

I have to find a way to uniform my products.

I start to get my product to compare using the arrays of IDS passed from my compare view.

```
products = Products::Product.includes( { product_features_groups: [ { product_features: [:feature, :product_features_group] }] }).where(id: params["products"])
```

Then I think to map the products array to collect every product_features and then to map again to create an array of hashes where I have every feature and every feature group present in my products to compare. Then I add unique because of course I have to remove the duplicates, feaures that are present in more than one product...

```
compared_products = products.map{|p| p.product_features}.flatten.map{ |f| {feature_id: f.feature_id, features_group_id: f.feature_group.id, feature_name: f.feature.name, group_name: f.feature_group.name}}.uniq
```

The result now is something like this:

```
   {:feature_id=>5214, :features_group_id=>148, :feature_name=>"Materiale della scocca", :group_name=>"Design"},
 {:feature_id=>11025, :features_group_id=>148, :feature_name=>"Colore cinturino", :group_name=>"Design"},
 {:feature_id=>1721, :features_group_id=>27, :feature_name=>"Durata batteria", :group_name=>"Gestione energetica"},
 {:feature_id=>1025, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Microfono incorporato", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
 {:feature_id=>7610, :features_group_id=>5, :feature_name=>"Tipo di vetro", :group_name=>"Display"},
 {:feature_id=>3239, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Wi-Fi", :group_name=>"Connettività"},
 {:feature_id=>2433, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Altoparlanti incorporati", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
 {:feature_id=>1208, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Versione Bluetooth", :group_name=>"Connettività"}
```

Then I group then by group name

```
compared_products.group_by{|h| h[:group_name]}.values 

[[{:feature_id=>432, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Standard Wi-Fi", :group_name=>"Connettività"},
  {:feature_id=>23798, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Porta USB", :group_name=>"Connettività"},
  {:feature_id=>3239, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Wi-Fi", :group_name=>"Connettività"},
  {:feature_id=>1208, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Versione Bluetooth", :group_name=>"Connettività"},
  {:feature_id=>4163, :features_group_id=>12, :feature_name=>"Connessione cuffia", :group_name=>"Connettività"}],
 [{:feature_id=>6702, :features_group_id=>185, :feature_name=>"Cardiofrequenzimetro", :group_name=>"Caratteristiche"},
  {:feature_id=>9731, :features_group_id=>185, :feature_name=>"Accelerometro", :group_name=>"Caratteristiche"},
  {:feature_id=>9732, :features_group_id=>185, :feature_name=>"Giroscopio", :group_name=>"Caratteristiche"},
  {:feature_id=>16407, :features_group_id=>185, :feature_name=>"Motore per la vibrazione", :group_name=>"Caratteristiche"},
  {:feature_id=>4277, :features_group_id=>185, :feature_name=>"Gestione dati personali", :group_name=>"Caratteristiche"},
  {:feature_id=>8720, :features_group_id=>185, :feature_name=>"Sensore luce ambientale", :group_name=>"Caratteristiche"}],
 [{:feature_id=>2172, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Radio FM", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>8956, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Sistema operativo mobile supportato", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>3233, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Sistema operativo incluso", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>730, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Tipi schede di memoria", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>1013, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Produttore processore", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>47, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Modello del processore", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>6089, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Numero di core del processore", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>1025, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Microfono incorporato", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>2433, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Altoparlanti incorporati", :group_name=>"Prestazione"},
  {:feature_id=>8074, :features_group_id=>184, :feature_name=>"Fotocamera integrata", :group_name=>"Prestazione"}],
 [{:feature_id=>7605, :features_group_id=>148, :feature_name=>"Materiale cinturino", :group_name=>"Design"},
  {:feature_id=>17541, :features_group_id=>148, :feature_name=>"Misura del polso", :group_name=>"Design"},
  {:feature_id=>9397, :features_group_id=>148, :feature_name=>"Forma", :group_name=>"Design"}...
```

And now I have my results grouped by features group I have every feature_group and every features of my array of product and I can use this to create the row of my table. Then, for every product, if the feature is present I can insert the value in the cell and if the feature is not present I can leave a blank space in the cell.

Is there a less confused method to to something like this?
Is there something I can improve?

Comment: One thing you definitely should fix is explicitly writing `module Products; class Product` etc. None of those classes are a properly nested. See https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: @max is because every model of this "product" database is a subfolder in the model folder... app/models/products and Rails automatically loads models from subfolders but does expect them to have namespace.

Comment: I'm aware of how the autoloader works, and no using the scope is resolution operator is just a bunch of bugs waiting to happing and a bad practice.

Comment: Ah ok good to know, I will change that! In my model I specify the class name for every relation... I will fix that!

Comment: I'm still not completely sure how to solve this but you do have a a lot of redundancy and de-normalization going on in how your associations are set up. You should probably add a `belongs_to :feature_group` association to feature and get rid of   ProductFeaturesGroup. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/385a5c4f8d85557887602538c4cde5a2

Comment: Yes I know, but I build the database using as reference a json response from a server and I have some redundant data I have to remove. You are right, I don't need that joint table!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214008/discussion-between-roberto-pezzali-and-max).